# How to parse links from the string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string like "Go to stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com"
Now I want to parse link from this string using c#.
I wants the output in the following format.
"`Go to stack overflow <a href=http://stackoverflow.com target=_blank>http://stackoverflow.com</>`"

Is it possible in C#?

Comment: Yes it is, try to google for something like "c# regex link from string", one of the first hits is http://weblogs.asp.net/farazshahkhan/archive/2008/08/09/regex-to-find-url-within-text-and-make-them-as-link.aspx, you should find your way from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression with this pattern `^(https?://)?(([0-9a-z_!'().&=$%-]: )?[0-9a-z_!'().&=$%-]@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-z_!'()-]\.)([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-z]\.[a-z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/?)|(/[0-9a-z_!*'().;?:@&=$,%#-])/?)$`

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = @"Go to stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, 
    @"((?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*)",
    @"Go to stack overflow <a href=$1 target=_blank>$1</>");
```

---

Output:

`Go to stack overflow Go to stack overflow <a href=http://stackoverflow.com target=_blank>http://stackoverflow.com</>`